# Extrapolate a set of measurement data with Matlab

Tags: matlab, measurement, extrapolation

There is data given from a csv-File. It contains the resistance of a cooling metal piece at a certain time. The measuremnt started at t=7.8s. The task is to extrapolate the graph from 7.8s to 0s to determine the highest resistance and thus the maximum temperature. How can I acheive this using matlab? I tried the following that did not yield satisfying results.

```
data = csvread('05A_edit.csv');
time = data(:,2)+7.8;
resistance = data(:,3);
timep = linspace(0,7.8,167);
resistancep = interp1(time,resistance,timep,'linear','extrap');
plot(time,resistance,'b',timep,resistancep,'r');
```

The plot of the raw data looks the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BRok.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's the problem with your result?

Comment: It would just "continue" with a line that seems arbitrary and does not blend in well with the other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use fitting. Do you have ideas about your data? It looks exponential. I would use:

```
[fitresult, gof]=fit(x,y,'exp1')
Y1=fitresult (X1)
```